# Mathematica 9 can't integrate this function but earlier versions could

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

```
Integrate[ ArcTan[x]/(1 + x) Log[(1 + x^2)/2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

I used *Mathematica 9.0.1* on *Windows7 32bit*, *Mathematica 9*  cannot compute this, but Mathematica 8 gives `Pi^3/96`, is this a bug?

Comment: I get the same result with Mathematica 9, but, admittedly, it took 3 times as long as with v8...

Comment: I have to correct myself, I now (after quitting the kernel) get `Infinity` (as pointed out by Artes)... No clue what went wrong before.

Comment: @explorer Couldn't  `Mathematica 9`  really return any result or colud it return `Infinity` as I demonstrated in my answer? Have you tried to integrate `TrigToExp@ArcTan[x]` ?

Comment: Has this been fixed in Mathematica 10.0.2? Anyone?

Comment: Not fixed in 13.

Comment: This is fixed in around 13.2.1. Both this and Integrate[( 
    1/2 I Log[1 - I x] - 1/2 I Log[1 + I x])/(1 + x) Log[(1 + x^2)/
    2], {x, -1, 1}]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue reminds many similar problems with `Integrate`.
We have in `Mathematica 8.0.4`:

```
Integrate[ ArcTan[x]/(1 + x) Log[(1 + x^2)/2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> ```
> Pi^3/96
> ```

However in `Mathematica 9.0.1` it takes quite a long time yielding a different result:

```
Integrate[ ArcTan[x]/(1 + x) Log[(1 + x^2)/2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> ```
> Infinity
> ```

This is a bug, we can compare it with the `NIntegrate` result which yields the number numerically the same as in `ver. 8`.

Of course the result should be the same if we substitute `ArcTan` by its equivalent:

```
TrigToExp[ ArcTan[x] ]
```

> ```
> 1/2 I Log[1 - I x] - 1/2 I Log[1 + I x]
> ```

but now the result is the same as in `ver. 8`:

```
Integrate[ TrigToExp[ ArcTan[x]]/(1 + x) Log[(1 + x^2)/2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> ```
> Pi^3/96
> ```

Comment: This is now fixed at least in 13.2.1.