# Re[x] vs. x ∈ Reals in the context of Assuming

Tags: assumptions

Let's say that $x$ is some real valued number $>0$.
Are the following commands interchangeable in the context of using `Assuming`?

1. `Assuming[{Re[x] > 0}, Integrate[...,x]]`
2. `Assuming[{x ∈ Reals && x > 0}, Integrate[...,x]]`

Or, as I suspect, is this not true for the reason that `Re[x] > 0` should just mean that the Real component of $x$ is $>0$?  Also, is there a way to more compactly specify `{x ∈ Reals && x > 0}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `Re[x] > 0` means that the real part of `x` is positive, but it does not mean that the imaginary part is zero.  `Re[1+I] > 0` but `1+I` is not real.

However, `x > 0` is sufficient and (in Mathematica) implies that `x` is also real.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw some strange behavior for ConditionalExpression and it made me wonder, so I'll think more carefully about my integral.  I'll accept your answer after the timer allows me to.

Comment: "However, x > 0 is sufficient and (in Mathematica) implies that x is also real."  Hmm, I'm wondering if this is a little dangerous?

Comment: @user11959 How is it dangerous?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, $0$ lies on the imaginary axis as well, so someone who just assumes that the magnitude of some variable is non-zero might write that down, and provide the wrong set of assumptions for an integral (ignoring the possibility of an imaginary component).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I shouldn't say "dangerous", since I don't mean anything outside the context of this assumption being confusing.  I suppose you'd have to write $Norm[x]>0$ as an assumption to not to have this happen.

Comment: @user11959 Not `Norm`, but `Abs`, in this case.  The idea is that comparisons don't make sense for complex number.  As soon as you use a comparison, Mathematica assumed that the associated variable is real.  Yes, this is a peculiarity of Mathematica that you need to be aware of and not something immediately obvious.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can see why it makes sense, but I'm glad to have been explicitly told about it all the same, thanks for that.

Comment: @user11959 Regarding seeing `Re[z]>0` in `ConditionalExpression`s, that means exactly that the real part is greater than zero, not that the imaginary part is zero.  There's nothing weird about it.  Example: `Integrate[Exp[-z x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]`.  Mathematica assumes `z` to be complex here because I didn't explicitly tell it that it's real.

Comment: In general `x > a` implies that `x ∈ Reals`. However there might appear some problems. The main problem comes from the fact that various functions involve some internal bugs. I recommend reading carefully this answer [Issue with NSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391).

Comment: @Szabolcs What I meant about the strange behavior with ConditionalExpression was that the presented solution should not have been defined on the complex plane, so I thought Re[x]>0 was somehow compressing the statement "x must be real and >0".  However, it appears I could have been mistaken about the solution.

Comment: @Artes I enjoyed reading your answer quite a bit.  I wonder if your insight regarding Solve vs. NSolve applies also to indefinite vs. definite integration?

Comment: @user11959 Especially one should be careful working with `Integrate` since it is well known that there are various bugs and there are many posts describing them e.g. [Mathematica 9 can't integrate this function but earlier versions could](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/mathematica-9-cant-integrate-this-function-but-earlier-versions-could). It doesn't relate to definite vs. indefinite integration.