# One more question about Assumptions and Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

There are many questions about assumptions here. Many of them are problem specific. That is why I want to ask a question in the most general way. Why does Mathematica solves this

```
Assuming[{x < 0}, Integrate[1/x, x]]
```

as

```
Log[x]
```

and not

```
-Log[-x]
```

?

Comment: I think you mean `Log[-x]`, not `-Log[-x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Log[-x]` is not a correct result, but `Log[-x]` is.

In fact the expressions `Log[-x]` and `Log[x]` differ only in a constant `I Pi`, so both are correct antiderivatives for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

While the result given by Mathematica is correct, it is complex valued for `x < 0`.  I think you are looking for a real valued result.  I do not think it is possible to ask `Integrate` to *automatically* provide one.

For *definite* integrals this won't be a problem though as that complex constant is cancelled:

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, a, -1}, Assumptions -> a < -1]

(* ==> -Log[-a] *)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about the minus sign, I forgot to move it under `dx`. However, I have one more question about the different part of your answer. Here (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41112/12223) you said "`x > 0` is sufficient and (in Mathematica) implies that `x` is also real". So, does Mathematica assume `x` to be real or not?

Comment: @shalabuda Yes, `x<0` is equivalent to `x < 0 && Element[x, Reals]`.  It doesn't influence the result of the integral though.  `Log[x]` is a correct result for all complex (real or not real) `x`.

Comment: so, why does this `Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, Re[Integrate[1/x, x]]]` give `Re[Log[x]]` instead of `Log[-x]`? (sorry for asking these follow up questions, I'm trying to get an intuition of how Mathematica works)

Comment: Well, `Re[Log[x]]` *is* a correct answer to the question, right?  If you'd like to simplify `Re[Log[x]]` to `Log[-x]` with the assumption that `x<0`, you can use `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand@Re[Log[x]], x < 0]`.