# Bug in mathematica analytic integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 13.0 or earlier**

---

I found *Mathematica* provides me a wrong answer for a relatively simple analytically solvable integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
     Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]
```

Provides as a result `(2π)/b`, which is incorrect. The integral can be computed easily writing the integrand as a geometric series.

Additionally, you can compute it numerically

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

which produces the right result, different from `(2π)/b`.

Is this a very bad bug? or am I doing something wrong? What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: In case it helps, Maxima gives `2*%pi/b * (2*sqrt(1-b^2)+b^2-2)/(sqrt(1-b^2)+b^2-1)`. When computing with +i instead of -i in the exponential, it gives instead `2*%pi/b * (sqrt(1-b^2)-1)/sqrt(1-b^2)`, but it's actually the same.

Comment: Have a play with this `Manipulate` to see the dependence on `b` of the singularities of the integrand in the complex `Theta` plane: `Manipulate[ContourPlot[Abs[Exp[-I Theta]/(1 + b Cos[Theta]) /. {Theta -> ThetaR + I ThetaI}], {ThetaR, -1, 2 Pi + 1}, {ThetaI, -Pi - 1, Pi + 1}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 30}, Contours -> 50, Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2 Pi, 0}}]}], {{b, 0.5}, -1, 1}]`. You need to ensure that the path of integration goes appropriately around the singularities in order to get the intended result.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell Is there a way to Tell Mathematica that theta is real, and integration is done on the real interval (0,2pi). I don't have Mma at hand right now to do the test, but there seem to be an [option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html) `Assumption->Element[x,Reals]`

Comment: The `Manipulate` in my previous comment shows that the position of the singularities of the integrand depends strongly on the value of `b`, so I can't see how any automatic integration scheme - e.g. integration along real `Theta` - will necessarily give you the "right" answer. In general, the answer depends on how the integration path winds around the singularities. However, I concede that in this particular case I haven't looked closely at exactly what is going on, other than to observe the "wandering singularities", which alerts me to the need to take care.

Comment: I found a (dubious, but it works) series expansion in `b` approach that works. Compute the coefficient of `b^n` using `coeff[n_] = Integrate[Exp[-I Theta]/(1 + b Cos[Theta]) // SeriesCoefficient[#, {b, 0, n}] & // Evaluate, {Theta, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> (n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers)] // FullSimplify` - this takes a while to compute. Sum the series using `integral[b_] = (Sum[b^n coeff[n], {n, 0, Infinity}]) // FullSimplify`, which gives `((-2 + 2 b^4 + (-1 + b^2) Sqrt[1 + b^2] + Sqrt[1 + b^2] Sqrt[1 - b^4] + Sqrt[2 - 2 b^4] Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - b^4]]) \[Pi])/(b(-1 + b^4))`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell I'm not sure I understand the complex roots problem. Taking real and imaginary parts, the integrand is a rational function of trig functions, and at the very least the change of variable theta=2atan(u) will always work, and is quite automatic (easy to do in Maxima with `changevar` followed by `trigexpand` and `ratsimp`). This is an easy integral, even without series (of course, one has still to be careful with integration bounds).

Comment: My `Series` approach is offered only as a way of helping Mathematica to compute the answer that you seek. As for the complex roots problem, I don't have any inside knowledge about how Mathematica does its integrations or how it handles singularities that may (or may not) be important. See the answer from @artes below for more details on this, where I agree with the statement that this is all due to "imperfectness of symbolic integration". When there are singularities lurking around, you have to appeal to the underlying physics (or whatever) of the problem to decide how to handle them.

Comment: This appears to be due to a problem deep in `Limit`. Will try to sort it out (usual caveat: roughly even odds it sorts me out instead).

Comment: the bug is still present in MMA 11.2.0... Huh

Comment: Looks like bug is fixed. It now says this ConditionalExpression[(2*(-1 + b^2 + Sqrt[1 - b^2])*Pi)/(-b + b^3), Abs[(-1 + Sqrt[1 - b^2])/b] != 1]

Comment: Oh, my. In 13.3.0 vs 13.2.1 the result is now slightly different. See where Abs is placed. ConditionalExpression[(
 2 (-1 + b^2 + Sqrt[1 - b^2]) \[Pi])/(-b + b^3), (1 - Sqrt[1 - b^2])/
  Abs[b] != 1]

Comment: BTW, in 13.2.1 the NIntegrate magic fails.

Answer (score 33):

This is indeed a serious and problematic issue.
We know many similar problems with symbolic integration which provides `Integrate`. There were some improvments in newer versions of the system but also some issues become worse, see e.g.  [Mathematica 9 can't integrate this function but earlier versions could](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/mathematica-9-cant-integrate-this-function-but-earlier-versions-could/26930#26930).

). One can find more problems looking for tags [calculus-and-analysis](/questions/tagged/calculus-and-analysis) and [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).
The bigger problem is that *Wolfram Research Inc.* seems not to be sure how to remove completely such bugs from the system.
There are a few things to say:

- possibly most general symbolic integration is a really difficult issue which needs many supplementing rules.
- basically there is no system free of any bugs (see e.g. [The Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) by Donald Knuth).
- a natural way of development of such a sophisticated system as *Mathematica* assumes a step by step process rather than finding a universal key opening all doors.

The problem we encounter here most likely comes from the fact that underlying complex functions behind the symbolic result are not defined in the whole complex plane, see closely related post: [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082).
We can see that we can compute the indefinite integral:

```
f[θ_] = FullSimplify[ Integrate[ Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]), θ], 
                                   0 <= θ <= 2 π && -1 < b < 1]
```

> ```
> -((I ((2 ArcTan[(1 + b E^(-I θ))/Sqrt[-1 + b^2]])/Sqrt[-1 + b^2] 
> - Log[ 2 E^(-I θ) (1 + b Cos[θ])]))/b)
> ```

In fact we have

```
D[ f[θ], θ] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> E^(-I θ)/(1 + b Cos[θ])
> ```

However as `b` is close to `-1` or `1` then this term `1 + b Cos[θ]` in the denominator becomes large when `θ` is close to `0` and then `ArcTan` and `Log` functions should be supplemented with an appropriate phase rule to get reliable results.

Interestingly this definite integral could be computed in *Mathematica 7*

```
Integrate[ Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]), {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> -1 < b < 1]
```

> ```
> (2 (1 - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) π)/b
> ```

The last result seems to be numerically compatibile with that of `NIntegrate` however it could be computed with certain phase rule which in general would be unnecessarily too restrictive yielding incorrect results in another cases. Taking into account the above remarks we would rather say that these incorrect results are rather due to imperfectness of symbolic integration (expected in future versions as well, in different forms though) than just a simple bugs.

Comment: (+1) *"a natural way of development of such a sophisticated system as Mathematica assumes a step by step process rather than finding a universal key opening all doors"*. I am totally agree. I can also say that the `NIntegrate` framework is implemented through the step-by-step approach in rather transparent and controllable way for a user (although insufficiently documented as always in *Mathematica*).

Answer (score 16):

[Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes) gives a good overview of the problems inherent in symbolic integration.  Changing the form of the integral can yield different results, but then the problem is determining the correct one.

Using [`ExpToTrig`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExpToTrig.html) on the integrand yields a different result:

```
ans1 = Integrate[Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]),
  {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]
ans2 = Integrate[Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]) // ExpToTrig,
  {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]
(*
  (2 π)/b
  ConditionalExpression[(2 (1 - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) π)/b, b != 0]
*)
```

We can compare the two answers.  Turning off [symbolic preprocessing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#12996145) ensures that the NIntegrate will use the formula just as we pass it.  (One can achieve a similar effect by defining `f[θ_?NumericQ] := Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ])` and using `f[θ]` for the integrand.

```
Block[{b = 0.5},
 {NIntegrate[Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]),
   {θ, 0, 2 π}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}],
  ans1, ans2}
 ]
(*
  {-1.94402 + 3.65803*10^-16 I, 12.5664, -1.94402}
*)
```

So the second method seems to give a correct result.  More values of `b` could be checked for further verification.

Another way to modify the form of the integral is to change the interval:

```
Integrate[Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]),
 {θ, -π, π}, Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]
(*
  ConditionalExpression[(
   2 (1 - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) π)/b, (b != 0 && Re[1/Sqrt[b]] != 0) || b < 0]
*)
```

Or one can break down the real and imaginary parts (the third one, with the parts combine is basically what `ExpToTrig` does):

```
Integrate[Cos[θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]),
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]
Integrate[Sin[θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]),
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]

Integrate[(Cos[θ] - I Sin[θ])/(1 + b Cos[θ]),
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> b < 1 && b > -1]

(*
  ConditionalExpression[(2 (1 - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) π)/b, b != 0]
  ConditionalExpression[0, b != 0]

  ConditionalExpression[(2 (1 - 1/Sqrt[1 - b^2]) π)/b, b != 0]
*)
```

One thing worth noting is that in this form, the integrands are real-valued functions (ignoring the complex coefficient in the third form) of real variables.  In fact, they are rational functions of sine and cosine, which can be converted to rational function via substitution, although I do not know how *Mathematica* handles them.  The `Exp[I θ]` probably causes *Mathematica* to invoke a different algorithm to deal with functions of a complex variable.

If one wants, may do the substitution `θ -> 2 ArcTan[t]`, although this will be equivalent to the integral from `-π` to `π`:

```
Integrate[TrigExpand@FullSimplify[
    Exp[-I θ]/(1 + b Cos[θ]) Dt[θ] /.
      θ -> 2 ArcTan[t], t ∈ Reals] /. Dt[t] -> 1,
 {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> -1 < b < 1]
(*
  (2 (π - π/Sqrt[1 - b^2]))/b
*)
```