# Suspected bug in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

In version 10.0:

```
Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[t]), {t, 0, 2 Pi},  Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]
(* (2 Pi)/(a^2 - b^2) *)
Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[t + t0]), {t, 0, 2 Pi},  Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]
(* 0 *)
```

However, a phase shifting on `t` should not affect the integral.

Comment: Maybe related to [48437](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48437/134) ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Quite similar.

Comment: Indeed, it is related.  It seems surprising that this problem has not been fixed after so many months.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, yes, same thing under 10.0.2.

Comment: If the imaginary part of `t0` is greater than `2 ArcTanh[(a - b)/(a + b)]`, then the integral is zero.  However, I still get zero (erroneously) if the assumption `Element[t0, Reals]` is added.

Comment: This will give the right answer: `Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[t + t0]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> a > b > 0 && -Pi < t0 < Pi]`.  The problem I suspect is that the integral cannot really be done by substitution `t = 2 ArcTan[u/2]`, since you have to count how many times the angle winds around the origin.

Comment: Appears fixed in 10.1.0.

Comment: In version `10.2`, I get the following solution for the second integral:$$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{2 \pi }{a^2-b^2},-3 \pi \leq \Re(\text{t0})\leq -\pi \land \Im(\text{t0})=0\right]$$

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be fixed in 10.1.0:

```
Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[t]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]
(* (2 π)/(a^2 - b^2) *)

Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[t + t0]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > b > 0}]
(* ConditionalExpression[(2 π)/(a^2 - b^2), -3 π <= Re[t0] <= -π && Im[t0] == 0] *)
```