# Possible bug in integration involving $\cos (n \phi)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, assumptions

I wanted to verify the integral $\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\phi}{(a^2+b^2)+(a^2-b^2)\cos(n\phi)}=\frac{\pi}{ab}$ (where $b>a>0$ and $n$ is a positive integer).

Individual values of $n$ work:

```
$Assumptions = {b > a > 0};

Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2Pi}]
*** Pi/(ab) *** 

Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[2 x]), {x, 0, 2Pi}]
*** Pi/(ab) *** 

Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[3 x]), {x, 0, 2Pi}]
*** Pi/(ab) ***
```

and so on.

But then, when I want to solve it for general $n$, I get:

```
$Assumptions = {b > a > 0, n \[Element] Integers, n >= 1};

Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[n x]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
*** Pi/(abn) ***
```

What is going on? (I'm using 11.0.1.0 on OSX.)

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag when asking new questions (see tag description).

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, but I noticed you wrote $cos^2$ initially but `cos[]` (not squared) in the code.

Comment: Oh, that's a typo, I'll fix it now, thanks.

Comment: When I did `Block[{$Assumptions = {b > a > 0, n \[Element] Integers, n >= 1}}
 , Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[n x]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]`, I got `0`. (v10.0 on Mac OSX).

Comment: Even without `Block` I get zero for v 11.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Furthermore, `Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[n x]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> {a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals, n ∈ Integers, n >= 1}], followed by `FullSimplify[%, {b > a > 0, n ∈ Integers, n >= 1}]` gives `π/(a b n)`, not `0`.  Also, `GenerateConditions -> True` doesn't.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Bug still present in MMA 11.2.0

Answer (score 5):

There are similar integrals with bugs, some of which have been fixed, such as 
[Suspected bug in Integrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69517/suspected-bug-in-integrate).

It seems that the branch cuts in the antiderivative are ignored, the antiderivative containing an `ArcTan`:

```
Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[n x]), x]
(*  ArcTan[(b Tan[(n x)/2])/a]/(a b n)  *)
```

One way to get the desired result is to integrate over just one period and multiply:

```
n*Integrate[1/((a^2 + b^2) + (a^2 - b^2) Cos[n x]), {x, 0, 2 Pi/n}, 
  Assumptions -> {b > a > 0, n ∈ Integers, n >= 1}]
(*  π/(a b)  *)
```

It should be reported to WRI, so that they might try to fix it.

Comment: It's quite difficult to figure out or in other ways work with parametrized branch cuts. I would be surprised if this can be improved any time soon.