# Symbolic integration error

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

I'm running *Mathematica* 10.0.0 and encountered a disturbing error in the symbolic integration of a rather simple function

```
Integrate[(1 - x)*(1 + 2*x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]/Pi
```

The correct value for this integral is 15 (and NIntegrate gives that correctly) but *Mathematica* evaluates it symbolically as 1/π+29/2. I tried Wolfram Alpha, and it also gives the wrong answer. Any idea what is going on?

[image: incorrect Wolfram Alpha symbolic evaluation of this integral]

the correct answer is 15π=47.1239

---

splitting the integrand into two parts does give the correct answer 15,

```
Integrate[(1 + 2*x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]/Pi - 
 Integrate[x*(1 + 2*x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]/Pi
```

somehow *Mathematica* has difficulty with square root singularities in the integrand?

Comment: Are you that Carlo Beenakker ? Anyway this seems better `int = Integrate[(1 - x)*(1 + 2*x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2], x]` and then `Limit[int, x -> 1] - Limit[int, x -> -1]`.

Comment: thanks, actually splitting the integrand in two parts also gives the correct answer, but I do find it worrisome that I need to take these precautions for what is a simple square-root singularity.

Comment: Hmm...it gets this equivalent integral right: `Integrate[(1 + 2*x)^6*Sqrt[(1 - x)/(1 + x)], {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: This works, too: `Integrate[(1 - x)*(1 + 2*x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> False]`

Comment: This also works: displace the endpoints of the integration, evaluate the integration, then move the endpoints back to their original locations: `Integrate[1/\[Pi] ((1 - x) (1 + 2 x)^6)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1 + a, 1 + a}] /. a -> 0`.

Comment: Will investigate..

Comment: Also this bug I reported three years ago, never fixed:
`$Assumptions = w ∈ Reals;
 FEx[w_] = (I E^(-25 + 5 I w - w^2/4) Sinh[5 w])/Sqrt[2];
 NIntegrate[(FEx[w])\[Conjugate]*FEx[w], {w, -∞, ∞}]
 NIntegrate[(FEx[w])\[Conjugate]*
      FEx[w], {w, -∞, ∞}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]`

Comment: @xslittlegrass I am not able to figure out what might be the issue you are reporting. If it was this `NIntegrate[FEx[w]*Conjugate[FEx[w]], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]` (or same, but with `Integrate`) then I do not see an incorrect result. In any case, sending a report via comment, without proper formatting of the input and without full explanation of the issue, is not all that sensible in terms of getting it addressed.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau sorry for the confusion. With the same assumption `$Assumptions = w ∈ Reals;`, on my computer I get different result for these two cases: (1) `NIntegrate[(FEx[w])\[Conjugate]*FEx[w], {w, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` (2) `NIntegrate[(FEx[w])\[Conjugate]*
  FEx[w], {w, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]`. I reported to the technical support three years ago, and it was confirmed. I thought this is related to the bug here. I will send a proper report with explanation to the support.

Comment: @xslittlegrass As formatted (above), these will be unlikely to behave at all: the "conjugate" appears as a symbol multiplying `FEx[w]`. When I rewrite as `Conjugate[FEx[w]]` it seems to go better, and both cases agreed.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have a screenshot [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58990/1364), also for your reference, the ticket number is "TS 33505" when I reported last time.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Thanks, the new post is helpful. I'll have a look. Definitely a bug of some sort.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for confirming that :)

Comment: For reference: 5.2 returns the correct answer. It seems tweaks to the internal algorithms inadvertently introduced this bug in later versions up until the fix.

Answer (score 17):

Having experienced similar problematic issues with *Mathematica* I instantly thought that expanding the fraction in the integrand i.e. applying `Appart` could resolve the problem, and indeed it does:

```
Integrate[ Apart[(1 - x)(1 + 2x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2]], {x, -1, 1}]/Pi
```

> ```
> 15
> ```

These arguments apply to this case as well [Bug in mathematica analytic integration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integration/48119#48119) i.e.

> ... underlying complex functions behind the symbolic result are not
>   defined in the whole complex plane...

Whenever an indetermined integral involves `ArcSin`, `ArcCos`, `ArcTan` etc. (here we have `ArcSin[x]`) one should carefully compare numerical and indetermined integrals remembering that *Mathematica* functions may have some arbitrary branch cuts in the complex plane. For a related issue see also [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090) where various user defined branch cuts of analytic functions are compared.

Comment: oddly it gets it correct if we split up the integral as `Integrate[ .. ,{x,-1,1/2}]+Integrate[..,{x,1/2,1}]` (depending on where you make the cut you get either the right or the wrong result.. )

Answer (score 4):

**Main**

The bug cannot only be attributed to the Sqrt in the integrand. It is trickier.

In fact, define for t=0,1,2,...

```
f[t_] := Integrate[(1 - x)*(1 + 2*x)^t/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]/Pi
```

Then

```
{#, f[#]} & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

(* Out[33]= {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {6, (
  1 + (29 \[Pi])/2)/\[Pi]}, {7, (1 + (71 \[Pi])/2)/\[Pi]}, {8, (
  1 + (181 \[Pi])/2)/\[Pi]}} *)
```

Which is correct for t=0..5 but becomes wrong for t=6, 7, ... but in all cases the branch cut problem of the Sqrt in the integrand should appear. So what is so special about t=6, 7, ...?

I don't have an answer but have continued the study: writing in the integrand (for |x|<1)

```
Simplify[(1 - x)/Sqrt[1 - x^2 ] == Sqrt[(1 - x)/(1 + x)], -1 <= x <= 1]

(* Out[40]= True *)
```

the integral becomes

```
f1[t_] := Integrate[Sqrt[(1 - x)/(1 + x)] (1 + 2*x)^t, {x, -1, 1}]/Pi
```

At integer values we have

```
{#, f1[#]} & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

(* Out[37]= {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {6, 15}, {7, 36}, {8, 91}} *)
```

and no problem is encountered.

The integral can even be solved for real t (do the indefinite integral, then insert the limits x=1, x=-1), with the analytical result

```
f2[t_] := -3^t (-2 Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -t, 1, 4/3] + Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -t, 2, 4/3])
```

Except for non negative integers t this function is complex as can be seen by plotting it:

```
Plot[{Re[#], Im[#]} &[f2[t]], {t, -7, 7}]

(* graph now shown here *)
```

Best regards,
Wolfgang

**EDIT 07.09.14 00:55**

Even stranger:

```
Integrate[(1 + 2 x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2] (1 - x), {x, -1, 1}]/Pi

(* Out[88]= (1 + (29 \[Pi])/2)/\[Pi] *)
```

Decomposing trivially (1-x) = 1 - x
gives two integer parts

```
Integrate[(1 + 2 x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2] (1), {x, -1, 1}]/Pi

(* Out[91]= 141 *)

Integrate[(1 + 2 x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2] (-x), {x, -1, 1}]/Pi

(* Out[92]= -126 *)
```

and added = 15, as it should be

% + %%

(* Out[93]= 15 *)

Regards, Wolfgang

Answer (score 4):

fixed in **10.1** (windows):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code:

```
Clear[x]
Integrate[(1 - x)*(1 + 2*x)^6/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]/Pi
```