# Is this a bug in NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

**Fixed in 10.1**

---

**Bug is present as of version 10.0.2** checked on windows 7, 64 bit

---

Is this a bug or I missed something? `NIntegrate` seems to give a different answer for the same integrand when the option `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` is given.

```
$Version
(* "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)" *)

$Assumptions = w ∈ Reals;
FEx[w_] = (I E^(-25 + 5 I w - w^2/4) Sinh[5 w])/Sqrt[2];
NIntegrate[Conjugate[FEx[w]]*FEx[w], {w, -∞, ∞}]
NIntegrate[Conjugate[FEx[w]]*FEx[w], {w, -∞, ∞}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
(* 0.313329 + 0. I *)
(* 0.626657 + 0. I *)
```

version 10

[image]

version 9

[image]

version 8

[image]

It seems to have worked in version 7.

version 7

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it was Daniel Lichtblau who added the tag [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs), I would say the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Therefore, should be reported to Wolfram Technical Support.

Comment: @rhermans. I think you can take that as done.

Comment: Can you explain why? Is it in the sense that you trust somebody already did, you know somebody did, or is it that Wolfram Technical Support actually participates in here?

Comment: @rhermans. Google "Daniel Lichtblau".