# How to numerically integrate this integral

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

[image]
I am unable to do this definite integral in *Mathematica 9*.
Is there any command so that I can get the numerical value of the above integration?

Code:

```
A1 = (A*2^2*Sin[theta]*Cos[theta])/((1 - (2^2*Cos[theta]^2)^2))
A3 = NIntegrate[A1, {theta, 0, (Pi/2)}]
```

Comment: You have to give a value for `A` in order to evaluate `A1` or `A3` numerically.

Comment: You could just take the `A` outside the integrand, and have your answer as a function of `A`, but then you have to deal with the fact that `A1` diverges when `theta=Pi/3`.

Comment: @Jason B thank you so much sir

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: To closevoters: The problem is not that one cannot integrate numerically functions involving symbolic constants, therefore you have no reason to close it.

Answer (score 9):

Besides trivial observations that one cannot evaluate numerically integrals involving symbolic constants there are more interesting aspects of the problem at hand. First one should realize that a standard **numeric approach is not appropriate for this kind of problems**, since the integrand involves singular points (zero in the denominator) thus it is not convergent and therfore numeric integration produces large errors. So this is not a satisfactory answer:

```
A NIntegrate[(4  Sin[θ] Cos[θ])/((1 - (2^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2)), {θ, 0, π/2}]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of 
> the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, 
> or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive 
> bisections in  θ near {θ} = {1.04922}.
> NIntegrate obtained 1.2201346660089964` and 1.3407904317156392` for the integral 
> and error estimates. >>
>
>
> 1.22013 A
> ```

As we'll see a correct answer is very different however one finds it within the error estimate.

### General symbolic integral

We can find that the symbolic integral (in the Riemann sense) is not convergent in the given range:

```
Integrate[( 4 A Sin[θ] Cos[θ])/((1 - (2^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2)), {θ, 0, π/2}]
```

> ```
> Integrate::idiv :"Integral of (Cos[θ]\Sin[θ])/(1-16\Cos[θ]^4) 
>                   does not converge on {0,π/2}."
> ```

We find the range where denominator does not vanish

```
Reduce[ 1 - 16 Cos[θ]^4 != 0 && Pi/2 > θ > 0, θ]
```

> ```
> 0 < θ < π/3 || π/3 < θ < π/2
> ```

Now we can find the symbolic integral assuming e.g. that the lower limit of integration is larger than `π/3` (we should also assume an appropriate upper bound):

```
int[A_, B_] = 
  Integrate[( 4 A Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/( 1 - 16 Cos[θ]^4), {θ, B, π/2}, 
              Assumptions -> 1 > A > 0 && π/3 < B < π/2]
```

> ```
> 1/4 A Log[-1 - 2/(1 + 2 Cos[2 B])]
> ```

We should compare numerical and symbolic results  (see e.g. [Symbolic integration error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/symbolic-integration-error/58945#58945)), e.g.:

```
NIntegrate[(4  Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/( 1 - 16 Cos[θ]^4), {θ, (4 π)/9, π/2}]
```

> ```
> 0.0606024
> ```

```
int[1, (4 π)/9]
```

> ```
>  1/4 Log[-1 - 2/(1 - 2 Cos[π/9])]
> ```

```
N @ %
```

> ```
> 0.0606024
> ```

So we have a reliable symbolic result.

### Solution

A recommended approach is to calculate the given integral in a principal value sense, there is the appropriate option in the `Integrate` function:

```
Integrate[( 4 A Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/(1 - 16 Cos[θ]^4), {θ, 0, π/2}, 
            PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> ```
> 1/4 A Log[5/3]
> ```

now we can define an adequate numeric function:

```
nint[A_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := 
  N @ Integrate[( 4 A Cos[θ] Sin[θ])/(1 - 16 Cos[θ]^4), {θ, 0, B},  
                 PrincipalValue -> True]
```

e.g.

```
nint[ 1, π/2]
```

> ```
> 0.127706
> ```

Therefore a "numerical" answer to the question is `0.127706 A`.

### Solution 2

Another approach would integrate numerically the integrand separately for the both sides of the singularity, a rough approach is

```
nint2[δ_?NumericQ] /; 0 < δ < π/6 := 
  A NIntegrate[(4  Sin[θ] Cos[θ])/((1 - (2^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2)), {θ, 0, π/3 - δ}]   
  + A NIntegrate[(4  Sin[θ] Cos[θ])/((1 - (2^2 Cos[θ]^2)^2)), {θ, π/3 + δ, π/2}]
```

Let's check how it works for a small value of `δ`

```
 nint2[0.0005]
```

> ```
> 0.127418 A
> ```

This approaches quite satisfactory to the real value, if we need higher acurracy one would increase the default `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: thank you so much for ur kind help

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Artes, this integral has meaning only under Cauchy principal value. Luckily, `NIntegrate` has this strategy (explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#2)):

```
NIntegrate[(4 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]])/(1 - 16 Cos[\[Theta]]^4), {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/2}, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

> 0.127706

Note that the position of the sigularity has to be specified in the interval. *Mathematica* will automaticly take advantege of the fact that the integral cancels in the vicinity of the sigularity.