# NIntegrate and Integrate giving different results for ill-behaved function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic, complex, singularity

I'm trying to integrate the following function with Mathematica 8:

$$ I(a,b)= \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x\int_0^1\mathrm{d}y \,\theta(1-x-y) \frac{1}{x a^2-y(1-y)b^2},$$
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function. However, I find different results with Integrate or NIntegrate and I don't understand why.

More specifically, for a=100 and b=90:

```
NIntegrate[HeavisideTheta[1 - x - y]/(x a^2 - y (1 - y) b^2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

gives

```
0.0000927294,
```

while

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[1 - x - y]/( x a^2 - y (1 - y) b^2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

gives

```
+0.0000600275+0.000314159 I.
```

What is the correct result? Why does Integrate give a complex result?

Comment: Various closely related questions have been asked several times, I remember these questions since I answered them: [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082), [Bug in mathematica analytic integration?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integration) and [Symbolic integration error](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/symbolic-integration-error/58945#58945). These should clarify the issue.

Comment: V10.0.2.0 behaves differently.  `NIntegrate` gives failure-to-converge error messages before giving the answer `0.0000927294`.  Adding the option `AccuracyGoal -> 20` gives `0.` as the answer with no error messages.  `Integrate`, on the other hand, returns only a partially integrated solution.

Comment: We deal with an improper double integral: look at the result of `ContourPlot[{(x 100^2 - y (1 - y) 90^2) == 0, 1 - x - y == 0}, {y, 0, 
  1}, {x, 0, 1}]`. It's unclear whether the integral under consideration txists at all. @bbgodfrey counts the iterated integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reversing the order of integration produces a solution:

```
ans= Integrate[HeavisideTheta[1 - x - y]/(x 100^2 - y (1 - y) 90^2), {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]
(* Log[(100*10^(38/81))/(81*19^(19/81))]/10000 *)

N[ans]
(* 0.000060027526501455836 *)
```

Solutions of this sort are what I would expect based on outlining a pencil-and-paper derivation.

Attempting to solve the integral numerically produces error messages.  For instance,

```
NIntegrate[HeavisideTheta[1 - x - y]/(x 100^2 - y (1 - y) 90^2), {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  MinRecursion -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 60]
```

produces

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.0000591404833446268` and 0.0003356281358114434` for the integral and error estimates. >>
(* 0.0000591404833446268 *)
```

Of course,`NIntegrate` has many options, and one or more of them may produce an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR Use `HeavisideTheta`'s properties before integration.**

---

This is my strategy.

First the `HeavisideTheta` gives you the following integration limits:

1. $$0\leq y \leq 1-x \qquad \& \qquad 0\leq x \leq 1$$
2. $$0\leq x \leq 1-y \qquad \& \qquad 0\leq y \leq 1$$

In both cases I used `Integrate` first then `NIntegrate`.

---

***In the first case*** I could not integrate numerically beacuse of a divergence in the result of the symbolical integration; in fact I had:

```
Integrate[1/(100^2 x - y (1 - y) 90^2), {y, 0, 1 - x}]

Plot[%,{x,0,1}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

$$\dfrac{(\arctan(\frac{9}{\sqrt{-81 + 400 x}}) + 
 \arctan({\frac{9 (1 - 2 x)}{\sqrt{-81 + 400 x}})}}{(\frac{450}{\sqrt{-81 + 400 x}})}$$

[image]

Maybe someone can come up with a solution also for this case.

---

***In the second case*** I obtained for the symbolical integration:

```
Integrate[1/(100^2 x - y (1 - y) 90^2), {x, 0, 1 - y}]
Integrate[%, {y, 0, 1}]
N@%
(*0.0000600275 - 0.000314159 I*)
```

and for the numerical integration:

```
NIntegrate[
 Integrate[1/(100^2 x - y (1 - y) 90^2), {x, 0, 1 - y}], {y, 0, 1}]
(*0.0000600275 - 0.000314159 I*)
```