# How to avoid complex terms in the results given by Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

As shown by `In1`, integrating `Sqrt[x^2 - 1]/(a + x^2) (1/x)` returns a result with a complex terms; however, after I make a transformation as shown in `In2`, *Mathematica* gives a simpler form.

I have no doubt the two outputs are both right and are actually the same thing, but my question is: for the input as given in `In1`, is there any method that can be applied to the output of `In1` that will give the same output as `Out2`? That is, can the result of `In1` be transformed by *Mathematica* itself into the desired form, thus, making the integration easier?

In1:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 - 1]/(a + x^2) (1/x), {x, 1, t}, Assumptions -> t > 1 && a > 5]
```

[image]

In2:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[y - 1]/(a + y) (1/(2y)), {y, 1, t^2}, Assumptions -> t > 1 && a > 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Read theses closely related posts: [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082) and [Bug in mathematica analytic integration?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integration/48119#48119).

Comment: This is fixed now, before 13. Rubi's not needed anymore, same result even without it.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica is good in integration, but I think [Rubi's](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) Mathematica integration package produces more optimal results in general. See [this](http://12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/index.htm) for more examples.

In this case, Rubi produced the same result as your second integral (Rubi only does indefinite integration, but one can use limits to compute the definite integration (assuming it is valid to do so, i.e. the antiderivative that resulted is defined over the range on integration, etc..).

Compare the indefinite integration of your first example between Mathematica result and Rubi's

```
Clear[x, a];
r = Int[Sqrt[x^2 - 1]/(a + x^2) (1/x), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear[x, a];
r2 = Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 - 1]/(a + x^2) (1/x), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To evaluate the definite integral:

```
  sol = Limit[r, x -> t] - Limit[r, x -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare this to the result from your second example

```
Clear[y, a, t]
sol2 = Integrate[Sqrt[y-1]/(a + y)(1/(2 y)), {y, 1, t^2}, Assumptions -> t > 1 && a > 5];
Assuming[t > 1 && a > 5, Simplify[sol - sol2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I could not simplify Mathematica result to remove the complex result. Even using the assumptions you have.