# How to calculate a hard definite integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic, singularity

I have the following function of $4$ - variables

```
f1111[x1_, x11_, x2_, x22_] := (-(x1 - x11)^4 - 6(x1 - x11)^2 (x2 - x22)^2
                                 + 3(x2 - x22)^4)/(4π((x1 - x11)^2 + (x2 - x22)^2)^3)
```

the variables are `x1, x11, x2` and `x22`.

*`Wolfram Mathematica`* can easily calculate the indefinite integral of this function.

```
FullSimplify[ Integrate[ f1111[x1, x11, x2, x22], x1, x11, x2, x22]]
```

The result is a very long function. However, my problem is a definite integral, which needs to be calculated in a square domain,

```
Integrate[ f1111[x1, x11, x2, x22], 
             {x1, -0.5, -0.25}, {x11, -0.25, 0}, {x2, -0.5, -0.25}, {x22, -0.5, -0.25}]
```

The above code doesn't work, waiting for about 30 minutes  nothing happened.

I tried numerical integration with different methods (`LocalAdaptive` and `GlobalAdaptive`), and I also tried to increase `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`, but the problem of singularity and low convergence is always present.

**Is there a way to get the correct solution in a reasonable time?**

Because I will need to perform this integration several times.

Comment: NIntegrate throws up a couple of warnings but gives approx -0.00855780339 as the result quickly. Did you try this ?

Comment: Yes I did, but with Trapezoidal method I get different result, - 0.00709118.

Comment: So it's not a problem if Mathematica gives warnings, the result can still be correct?

Comment: Well the warnings are thrown up for a reason ! Whether it is a problem or not should be decided by us. As the warnings indicate there could be convergence issues. I would try with WorkingPrecision and other options to check for convergence.

Comment: `Timing[Integrate[f1111[x1,x11,x2,x22],{x1,-1/2,-1/4},{x11,-1/4,0},{x2,-1/2,-1/4},{x22,-1/2,-1/4}]]` returns `{67.340763, (-11*Log[5]+4*(Pi-4*ArcTan[2]+Log[128]))/ (128*Pi)}` with no warnings or errors and which should be exactly correct. That number is approximately -0.0085637914008856298463472158822972

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and help Bill !!:)

Comment: Mathematica 101: Never mix inexact numbers with functions meant to be used to obtain analytical exact result.

Comment: Using Rubi(Rule-based Integration):``<<Rubi`;Integrate[Int[Int[Int[(-(x1-x11)^4-6 (x1-x11)^2 (x2-x22)^2+3 (x2-x22)^4)/(4 \[Pi] ((x1-x11)^2+(x2-x22)^2)^3),{x22,-(1/2),-(1/4)}],{x2,-(1/2),-(1/4)}],{x11,-(1/4),0}],{x1,-(1/2),-(1/4)}]//AbsoluteTiming`` returns `{8.25518,(4 Pi-16 ArcTan[2]+Log[268435456/48828125])/(128 Pi)}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We couldn't be well-satisfied taking the black box system results when having in mind that no computer system is free of bugs and that its various aspects related to symbolic integration may seem not quite perfect (see e.g.  this [remarks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integration/48119#48119)).  And so our purpose is to calculate this integral with more laborious approach, at least with a few steps which could be checked with a pencil at hand.  Nevertheless the system will tackle the problem clearly in a few times more efficient way.

The integrand appears to be quite symmetric and it is convenient to change variables and define a new function. We can see that

```
f1111[x + w, -x + w, y + z, -y + z] // Simplify
```

> ```
>  -((x^4 + 6 x^2 y^2 - 3 y^4)/(16 π (x^2 + y^2)^3))
> ```

and so we define new variables $$(x_1,x_{11}, x_2, x_{22}) \mapsto (x,w,y,z)=(\frac{x_1+x_{11}}{2}, \frac{x_1-x_{11}}{2}, \frac{x_2+x_{22}}{2},\frac{x_2-x_{22}}{2})$$
    and

```
f[x_, y_] := -((x^4 + 6 x^2 y^2 - 3 y^4)/(16 π (x^2 + y^2)^3))
```

we calculate the jacobian of this linear  transformation

```
Det @ D[{ x + w, w - x, y + z, z - y}, {{x, w, y, z}}]
```

> ```
>  4
> ```

The function `f` doesn't depend on `w` and `z` and so integration simplifies, however one has to calculate the integration region appropriately. We will integrate the function in two steps, first integrating `f` with respect `x` and `w` (the result will be stored in `if`) and then `if` with respect to `y` and `z`. Now we find appropriate ranges of variables.

```
x1x11 = {{-1/2, -1/4}, {-1/4, -1/4}, {-1/4, 0}, {-1/2, 0}, {-1/2, -1/4}};
x2x22 = {{-1/2, -1/2}, {-1/4, -1/2}, {-(1/4), -(1/4)}, {-1/2, -(1/4)}, {-1/2, -1/2}};
tsf = {(#1 - #2)/2, (#1 + #2)/2} &;
```

now we have

```
xw = tsf @@@ x1x11
yz = tsf @@@ x2x22
```

> ```
> {{-(1/8), -(3/8)}, {0, -(1/4)}, {-(1/8), -(1/8)}, {-(1/4), -(1/4)}, {-(1/8), -(3/8)}}
> {{0, -(1/2)}, {1/8, -(3/8)}, {0, -(1/4)}, {-(1/8), -(3/8)}, {0, -(1/2)}}
> ```

```
GraphicsRow[{Graphics[{Magenta, Thickness[0.025], Line[x1x11]}], 
             Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.025], Line[xw]}]}]
```

[image]

This picture for `x1x11` and `xw` is helpful for appropriate specifications of integration regions. Quite analogical is the region for `x2x22` and `yz`. Integration has to be divided in two subsets for the both regions `xw` and `yz`, and so (a simple  exercise is left for the reader why integration over `w` has been changed into multiplication by `(2 x + 1/2)` for `-(1/4)< x <-(1/8)`) and `(-2 x)` for `-(1/8) < x < 0`, as well as by `(2 y + 1/4)` for `-1/8 < y < 0` and `-2 y + 1/4` for `0 < y < 1/8`)

and finally we evaluate:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  if[y_] = Assuming[{-(1/8) < y < 1/8}, 
             4 (Integrate[f[x, y] (2 x + 1/2), {x, -(1/4), -(1/8)}] 
                 + Integrate[f[x, y] (-2 x), {x, -(1/8), 0}])];
  int = Simplify[ Integrate[if[y] (2 y + 1/4), {y, -1/8, 0}] 
                  + Integrate[if[y] (-2 y + 1/4), {y, 0, 1/8}]]]
```

> ```
> {11.3938, (-4π  + 8 ArcCot[2] + 8 ArcTan[1/2] + 28 Log[2] - 11 Log[5])/(128 π )}
> ```

This timing is for my old and slow laptop (i3, 1.9GHz, 4 GB RAM  )

```
N[int, 20]
```

> ```
>  -0.0085637914008856298463
> ```

Another way is exploiting appropriately `ImplicitRegion`, however we have performed this way because the transformation `tsf` is frequently used in physics  e.g. retarded and advanced variables.

Comment: The integrand is a rational function containing no symbolic parameters, and the bounds are likewise numeric. If `Integrate` is going to have issues it will be with assessing convergence of a multiple integral, not with the sorts of things that arise in more general cases. (This comment only pertains to the opening sentence of the response; the rest appears to be quite useful).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That opening sentence is a very general remark, not intended to be an explanation of the issue here. My intention was to demonstrate a pedestrian approach providing the correct answer, while the introduction says more or less: "Working with `Integrate` you have to be careful". I hope you haven't  taken that statement as a critics of the internal implementation of `Integrate`, being one of my favourite functions in `Mathematica` as can be seen from my activity on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do step by step indefinite integration.

With Rubi  https://rulebasedintegration.org/  i easily got the right result. Unfortunately indefinite integration with `Integrate`  failed. Didn't examine further why.

```
assum = Assumptions -> {-1/2 < x1 < -1/4, -1/4 < x11 < 0, -1/2 < 
 x2 < -1/4, -1/2 < x22 < -1/4};

int1[x1_] = 
Int[(-(x1 - x11)^4 - 6 (x1 - x11)^2 (x2 - x22)^2 + 3 (x2 - x22)^4)/(
4 \[Pi] ((x1 - x11)^2 + (x2 - x22)^2)^3), x1];

lim1 = Limit[int1[x1], x1 -> -1/4, Direction -> 1, assum] - 
Limit[int1[x1], x1 -> -1/2, Direction -> -1, assum];

int2[x2_] = Int[lim1, x2];

lim2 = Limit[int2[x2], x2 -> -1/4, Direction -> 1, assum] - 
Limit[int2[x2], x2 -> -1/2, Direction -> -1, assum] // 
Simplify[#, assum] &;

int3[x11_] = Int[lim2, x11];

lim3 = Limit[int3[x11], x11 -> 0, Direction -> 1, assum] - 
Limit[int3[x11], x11 -> -1/4, Direction -> -1, assum] // 
Simplify[#, assum] &;

int4[x22_] = Int[lim3, x22];

lim4 = Limit[int4[x22], x22 -> -1/4, Direction -> 1] - 
Limit[int4[x22], x22 -> -1/2, Direction -> -1] //   Simplify[#] &;

lim4 // ComplexExpand // N
(*   -0.008563791400885638`   *)
```