# How to perform symbolic integration of six variable function?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, functions, symbolic

I have a function of six variables in total - `x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33` and I need to perform symbolic integration to get a symbolic expression.

Before showing my function, I want to show from where does the function originates.

The 3D function `f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := -(1/(8 \[Pi])) Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]` is a fundamental solution of biharmonic equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation

```
∂^4f/∂x1^4 + ∂^4f/∂x2^4 + \
∂^4f/∂x3^4 + 
2 ∂^4f/(∂x1^2 ∂x2^2) + 
2 ∂^4f/(∂x1^2 ∂x3^2) + 
2 ∂^4f/(∂x2^4 ∂x3^2) == 0
```

I have written a partial differential equation in `Wolfram Mathematica` just for clarification. My three variables are `x1, x2, x3`.

Now, if I differentiate my function `f` four times with respect to variable `x1` I will get

```
difFunction = FullSimplify@D[f[x1, x2, x3], {x1, 4}]
```

which is a little bit more complicated expression.

Finally, the function I need to integrate symbolically is obtained by a change of variables in `difFunction` from `x1` to `x1 - x11`, from `x2` to `x2 - x22` and from `x3` to `x3 - x33`.

I end up with the function `g` of six variables in total `x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33`.

```
g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x11_, x22_, x33_] := -((
3 (4 (x1 - x11)^2 - (x2 - x22)^2 - (x3 - x33)^2) ((x2 - 
x22)^2 + (x3 - x33)^2))/(
8 \[Pi] ((x1 - x11)^2 + (x2 - x22)^2 + (x3 - x33)^2)^3.5))
```

I tried integrating this function with `Wolfram Mathematica 7`

```
Integrate[g[x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33], x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33]
```

but I `Wolfram Mathematica` wasn't able to evaluate this integral.

**Is there a way to simplify function `g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x11_, x22_, x33_]` so that I can evaluate this integral?**

**Or is there some other method which I can use to get the symbolic expression?**

Comment: I recommend taking  a closer look at this problem  (closely related)  [How to calculate a hard definite integral?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215399/how-to-calculate-a-hard-definite-integral)

Answer (score 2):

It integrates if (1) we replace your exponent $3.5$ by the exact $7/2$, and (2) we change the order of integration:

```
g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x11_, x22_, x33_] =
   -((3(4(x1-x11)^2-(x2-x22)^2-(x3-x33)^2)((x2-x22)^2+(x3-x33)^2))/
    (8π((x1-x11)^2+(x2-x22)^2+(x3-x33)^2)^(7/2)));

Integrate[g[x1, x2, x3, x11, x22, x33], x3, x33, x2, x22, x1, x11]
(*    lengthy output    *)
```

Comment: Dear Roman!
Thank you for your answer! 
Is there a way to get rid of a complex part of a expression?
Or to get complex and real part of this expression?

Comment: @CroSimpson2.0 indefinite integrals (antiderivatives) include an arbitrary offset constant, which may be complex-valued. If you don't like the offset constant, you can modify it as you wish. For example, evaluate the imaginary part and subtract it. Alternatively, if you compute a definite integral you won't get any imaginary parts.

Comment: How can I get imaginary part of this expression?

Comment: Aren't you rather looking for a definite integral at the end? If you are, then that's going to be much easier than figuring out the story of the six integration constants.

Comment: Yes I am. But to calculate the value of a definite integral I am using the symbolic expression, i.e. antiderivative.

Comment: Have you tried simply specifying the integration limits in `Integrate` instead of using the antiderivative? Multi-dimensional antiderivatives aren't quite as simple as one-dimensional ones.

Comment: I will try that as well.
Thx for the advice.